# INNER JOIN with position in second table

Tags: sql, inner-join

I'm running a `CodeIgniter` backend for a game, where the user info and a highscore table are saved in the database. Every user can only enter the highscore with his personal best, so there is only a single entry per user

Now I need to export that data for the customer so he can pick a random winner.
Basically I want to give him all the user data plus the users points and his position in the highscore table.

I'm having problems figuring out how to get the position in the highscore table.

Let's say my user tables looks like this

```
user_table
| id|name|
|...| ...|

highscore_table
|id |user_id|points|
|...|  ...  |  ... |
```

The SQL statement, not including the highscore position, looks like this

```
SELECT user_table.id, name, points
FROM user_table
INNER JOIN highscore_table ON user_table.id = highscore_table.user_id
ORDER BY name
```

The exported data should look like this

```
|id | name|points|hs_position|
|...| ... |  ... |    ...    |
```

Usually when I request the highscore, I do something similar but sort the data by `points`. This is just not an option here.

Can somebody tell me how to achieve this, lead me in the right direction or just plain and simple tell me that this is not possible?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what you are trying to do?

Comment: I think stackoverflow should add `a suggestion saying are you missing to add which RDBMS you're using`? when a question is tagged in sql or database tag?

Comment: Sorry everyone, for leaving out important info. It is a MySQL database, and I can't sort by points, because there is way more info for the user than I used above and the client has a clear expectation of how the exported data should look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a RDBMS that does not support ranking functions (such as SQLite), then one way of achieving this is via a subquery - like so:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, h.points, 
       (select count(*) + 1
        from highscore_table h2 
        WHERE h2.points > h.points) hs_position
FROM user_table u
INNER JOIN highscore_table h ON u.id = h.user_id
ORDER BY u.name
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/79180/3).

(If you want a dense-ranked high score, change `count(*) + 1` to `count(distinct h2.points) + 1`.)

Answer (score 2):

> I'm having problems figuring out how to get the position in the
>   highscore table.

If you're using SQL-Server you can use `DENSE_RANK` for the HS-Rank and `ROW_NUMBER` to get the row with the highest point per user:

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT user_table.id, 
                name, 
                points, 
                hs_position=Dense_rank() 
                              OVER( 
                                ORDER BY points DESC), 
                Personalbest_Num=Row_number() 
                                   OVER( 
                                     partition BY id 
                                     ORDER BY points DESC) 
         FROM   user_table 
                INNER JOIN highscore_table 
                        ON user_table.id = highscore_table.user_id) 
SELECT id, 
       name, 
       points, 
       hs_position 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  personalbest_num = 1 
ORDER  BY hs_position ASC, 
          name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution for MySQL:

```
SELECT user_table.id, name, points, hs_table.rank
FROM user_table
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT hs.*, IF(@prev != points, @pos:=@pos + 1, @pos) as rank
  , @prev:=points
  FROM highscore_table hs,
       (SELECT @pos:=0, @prev:=NULL) vars
  ORDER BY points DESC
) hs_table
 ON user_table.id = hs_table.user_id
ORDER BY name
```

People with the same amount of points will have the same rank.